# Log disabling in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to this logging module.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.disable = True
```

As per my understanding this should disable debug logs. But when it is  executed it prints debug logs also.

I have only debug logs to print. I dont have critical or info logs. So how i can disable this debug logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logging.disable is method, not a configurable attribute.

You can disable logging with :

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.disable

To disable all, call:

```
logging.disable(logging.DEBUG)
```

This will disable all logs of level DEBUG and below.

To enable all logging, do `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)` as it is the lowest level.

Comment: is there any function to enable it again?

Comment: It throws me following error.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 851, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 724, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can change to `level=logging.CRITICAL` and receive only critical logs

Answer (score 0):

the `level` argument in `logging.basicConfig` you've set to `logging.DEBUG` is the lowest level of logging which will be displayed.
the order of logging levels is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging-levels).

if you don't want to display DEBUG, you can either set `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`, or specify levels to be disabled via `logging.disable(logging.DEBUG)`